# Check if value from previous row in one column inserted has changed

Tags: mysql

Lets say we have a table that is

```
ID Value
1  2
1  3
1  4
2  9
2  98
2  1
3  2
3  98
3  7
```

I do a ORDER BY on the ID column but I want to check if the previous row Ive inserted is the same ID or not.

How do I check that? Possible will go in a trigger so I can use NEW.*

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this isn't possible. If I remember correctly, every SQL language looks at a database on a row by row (or record by record) basis. So it's not possible to go back to a previous row and check for something.

So if I were you, I would do this in the application or website where you are using the data. Then you can go back to the previous row and do the checks you want.

Comment: Can't use a OLD table or anything?